# IIS Web log performance, hourly VS daily

Tags: iis, logfiles

Is there any performance gain / loss for switching to hourly IIS logs v.s. daily IIS logs?

Our servers get hit very frequently throughout the day, roughly 20,000 hits per second in high traffic, and I'm trying to find a way to cut down the time it takes to delete / compress / move our log files, which can take up to 2 gigabytes per day.

I would think that the overhead of switching to an hourly file is minimal, and I've tried looking for comparisons on-line, but so far it's been inconclusive.

EDIT: The main reason we are looking to do this is to have a more efficient way of compressing / moving the logs to a different server and parsing them for errors.

EDIT 2: We're looking a balance between server performance and having things like 500 or 404 errors being reported in somewhat real time. My concern is that switching to hourly files will cause overhead for the server closing the old log file and generating a new log file hourly.

Comment: I don't know much about IIS, but in general I would feel that more (smaller) requests for the same amount of data would equal more overhead.

Comment: It's a balance between server performance and having things like 500 or 404 errors being reported in somewhat real time. my concern is that switching to hourly files will cause overhead for the server closing the old log file and generating a new log file hourly.

Comment: 2 GiB/day is only 25 KiB/second or 1.5 MiB/minute. Sounds like something you could log into SQL Server and query in real-time. Or just have a service reading the text-files updating a real-time cache of the last hourly errors.

Comment: You should expand upon the issue of 404/500 and the fear of overwriting old log files in your original question text.